# Relationship Type Between Comments and an App

Tags: django, sqlite, many-to-many, relationship, one-to-many

I'm new to setting up database schemas and am working a problem where I have multiple models that should contain a comments section. I'm using Django with SQLite for reference. For example I'll have Projects which are made up of Tasks. Each Project and Task should have a comments section.
Projects can contain many Tasks, but one task will only point to one Project (one to many using FK). I have one model for Comments that will ever only point to one Project or one Task, but Projects and Tasks will have multiple Comments.
I think what I want is a Many to one relationship on the Comments model, but then I would need multiple FK fields depending on where the comment lives (Project or Task). My full app will have 8-10 locations where we'd want to have comments. The other option is to have 8-10 tables for each Django app that needs comments. ex. ProjectComments model, TaskComments model, etc.

What's the best way to set this up?

Thanks in advance!

Based on the first answer, something like this?

```py
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField


# django model for comments

class Comment(models.Model):
    autor = models.ForeignKey('Users', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    content = RichTextField()
    conversation = models.ForeignKey('Conversation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Conversation(models.Model):
    pass


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = RichTextField()
    conversaton = models.ForeignKey('Conversation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = RichTextField()
    task = models.ForeignKey('Task', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey('Conversation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvSzI.png) I propose.

A `CommentSection may` link to either a `Task` or a `Project` through a nullable foreign key. Then each `Comment` links to a `CommentSection`.

Comment: Like the above? See the edited post - I can't seem to post code in this comment section.

Comment: @MikeDergance: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77411118/edit) the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django specifically, but that looks like a good layout!